# The usage of '-ing' and '-in' in writing

Tags: verbs, ing

Can someone explain to me why sometimes **V-ing** like *going* is abbreviated into *goin'* or *because* into *'cause*.

I don't understand when or how to use it in writing, especially in a novel (in dialogue). Often I see those in dialogue.

Comment: They are called elisions: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision

Comment: _'Cause_ as an abbreviation for _because_ is common in colloquial speech. It's often written _cos_ or even, more recently, _cuz_. Novelists sometimes try to represent a character's nonstandard speech in writing, for example _'ave_ for _have_. This was taken to extremes by some earlier writers portraying characters with regional accents, but it can make dialogue very difficult to read.

Comment: It isn't really nonstandard. It's normal speech, or an attempt to approximate it in the reader's mind's ear. It's just not very close to the spelling. Spaces between words and every syllable pronounced because it is spelled is not the way people talk. Not even close. So in dialog writers sometimes try to reproduce the sound; that's better than imputing attitudes that the other characters can't observe. It's always better if the reader comes to the conclusion the writer wanted them to without wondering about how it happened.

Comment: It accentuates that the speech is in a casual tone.

Comment: @Kate Bunting - a teacher at my junior school in London came from Worcestershire and pronounced 'because' as 'becuz', and a number of children took to spelling it like that as a result.

Comment: If you are writing a novel in English, you have to make  your own spelling choices to reflect the speech of your character. To cite every single typical written form that seeks to ape actual speech would take an entire book. in for ing is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So instead of saying it like the two words  BE COWS like it's spelt he said it like BE QUEUES for some reason? I do hope you realize that saying someone "pronounced 'because' as 'becuz'" is meaningless and confusing because you can never figure out what they actually said phonetically based on spelling. That's why we use the International Phonetic Alphabet here.

Comment: @user067531 No they aren’t. There is no /g/ sound in the word *writing*.

Comment: tchrist - "be cows"? Really? Where do they say it like that? In standard British English, we say 'because' like 'be coz' with the 'o' as in in hot, not, etc. The teacher said 'be cuz' with the 'u' as in hut, cut, etc.

Comment: @tchrist - https://books.google.it/books?id=-AL43YC_cZsC&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=goin+vs+going+elision&source=bl&ots=9J7nO-VUUR&sig=ACfU3U0XsHORgeuJUcVH6cbV96gophCTIQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKl6ih1bPnAhVCzqQKHRi2BPUQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=goin%20vs%20going%20elision&f=false

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How odd. I'm from Derbyshire, I don't have a strong regional accent but I've always thought of 'becuz' as the standard pronunciation. I'm amazed to find that online dictionaries give the British pronunciation as 'becozz'.

Comment: Kate - my father was from Castle Donington and he said 'becozz', but he was the posh one among his brothers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing is ordinarily phonemic, not necessarily phonetic.  Before a phonemic consonant cluster, tense /i:/ is ordinarily laxed to /i/, so you don't get */goi:ng/, but rather /going/. However, phonetically, after loss of the final /g/, [goi:n] is perfectly possible.  In fact, this is my usual pronunciation of the -/ing/ ending.

-/in/ is a dialectal variant (which you could hear in some British dialects, like that of Lord Peter Wimsey).

Comment: Walkin' etc. is used in AmE too.

Comment: @Lambie, I didn't intend to imply otherwise.

Comment: So, using it on any V-ing in dialogue is fine? There's no rule for when it cannot be used? If I recall, if the noun itself is on V-ing, you don't abbreviate it right? Like, "Her smiling like that makin' his face followed in a smile."

Comment: @GerryGiovan, So far as I know, the -ing suffix always works the same.  There might be some question about "farthing", "mine tailings", "lemming".

Comment: @GregLee Thanks for telling me. That will help a lot.